# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I might have done something really stupid. I was playing around with directories and what not, and now my tomcat server won't start my dynamic web project on eclipse. Please help. I don't know if this has something to do with the directory or not, but it's giving an error when I try to run my project in the server.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HttpServletRequest
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Tomcat crashes due to

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest
```

Please check if you have `javax.servlet-api` library in your classpath.

Answer (score 4):

Project -> Configure build path -> Add library -> Server Runtime -> Apache Tomcat V8. It works now. Could someone please tell me why it would have been removed though? It was working perfectly fine earlier today.

Answer (score 1):

Based on `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpServletRequest`, I think you do not add the **tomcat dependency libraries**.